# Height Map issue

Tags: texturing, transforms, height-map

I am working through the Blender guru anvil tutorial and I have run into an issue with the height map. When I load the height map info into the shader it looks like the scale is off and results in a texture that is more like a crumpled aluminum foil ball than rust on metal. I am not sure what is causing this issue as I have attempted to adjust the scale but haven't had any change from this action. Any advice helps, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: everything seems fine, choose Non-Color instead of sRGB in the Image Texture, and decrease the Strength value of the Bump node?

Answer (score 0):

We actually need the texture too. It doesn't seem embedded in the .blend file. Can you share it to me ? Like this, I can help you. Thanks.

Edit : The texture Color Space is "Non-Color" on the image texture node. Try put it to sRGB.

Comment: tried with sRGB, no change. Thanks for the help. https://www.mediafire.com/view/2ikw02qdrff0fg9/MetalCorrodedHeavy001_DISP16_4K_METALNESS.tif/file

Comment: Well, it works on my side : https://postimg.cc/TyvWd8fx
It's actually the Metalness Map, this is why you don't have the result you want.

I think this is the material ? https://www.poliigon.com/texture/metal-corroded-heavy-001/3219

Comment: My bad, it's actually the displacement map

Comment: With all textures i have this result. https://postimg.cc/18qJ7Zv1
It seems okay. Even if it's really bright, it needs some adjustments.

The .blend file : https://blend-exchange.com/b/zPLkAR8z/

Comment: followed your shader layout for just the heightmap and no change for either non-color or sRGB https://postimg.cc/V5kvfHf2  https://postimg.cc/ftTzbJNY